# The use of function html_entity_decode is forbidden. What should we use instead?

Tags: magento-1, coding-standards, magento-ecg

Ecg coding standards forbids using `html_entity_decode` method.

[image]

What should we use instead?

Comment: Any updates? What is the alternative and why is it forbidden?

Comment: Hi, found any alternated solution ?

Comment: They are probably no longer offering support to ECG on M1, as it was abandoned on Jul/2020.

Comment: Any news?
 I have the same warning in Magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I have used the alternate function i.e "htmlspecialchars_decode()"

```
 $returnArray["message"] = htmlspecialchars_decode(__(
                            "You added %1 to your shopping cart.",
                            $this->helper->stripTags($product->getName())
                        ));
```

Hope this solution may work for you.

Happy coding :)